# extract data from sql and insert into excel

Tags: mysql, excel

i am trying to get my data from mysql into excel im using

`insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;', 
    'SELECT * FROM [main]') select * from adel;`

to insert data in my excel but i keep on getting this error

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'main'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

can anyone give me some pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SELECT...INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) statement to store data into CSV-file that can be opened in MS Excel.

Also you can use direct [data export to *.xls file](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) using dbForge Studio for MySQL in command line mode.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u export mysql to csv, which can be opened with Excel. 
More info : http://www.electrictoolbox.com/create-csv-file-mysql-php/